# AWS CLI Command to create a version of an existing launch template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, launch-template

I have been trying to use aws cli command to create a version of an existing launch template and append a command to the userdata. With all my researches I couldn't do that.

PLease note, I have the neccessary IAM permissions to do that.

Please your contributions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post what commands have your tried and what error/result you are seeing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.